# Plotting evolutionary dynamics for iterated Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: python, matplotlib

For an assignment we had to develop the iterated rock-paper-scissors game using a q-learner/fictious play with as main objective the study of the evolutionary dynamics. When I did some research in literature the evolutionary trajects were all looking like the graph below:
[image: Evolutionary dynamics of the Rock-PaperScissors game.]

The output of my algorithm is the beliefhistory array

```
beliefhistory[0] = [1,0,0]
beliefhistory[1] = [0.5,0,0.5]
# this is just an example, but the main property of this array is that sum(beliefhistory[i]) = 1 and that it will approach [1/3,1/3,1/3] when i grows
```

So my question consists of two parts that i both would like to solve using python (or an alternative source)

- How would I bring down the 3D plot to an equilateral triangle
- How do I get the quiver plot like the example mentioned above (what kind of smoothing methods, etc exist)

Comment: https://github.com/marcharper/python-ternary